# Apache Avro vs Messagepack performance 2013

Tags: java, json, avro, messagepack

I have been reading a lot about Avro and Messagepack these days. Not sure which one to use when. One of the major questions I have is the difference in performance between the two on the following metrics:

- serialization speed
- deserialization speed
- size difference (across relevant types of messages: e.g. messages with different ratios of "overhead")

Comment: @chris-gerken and all: this is not asking to recommend a tool. This is asking for anyone with knowledge *specifically* about performance comparisons. It is a very discrete and answerable question. Please reopen.

Comment: I edited the question to respect the title-question as well as removing vauge exposition and explanations specific to Trekkie's project

Comment: @BT. Thanks for editing. Please vote for reopening, if you think it can be reopened.

Comment: I don't think i have the reputation to vote for reopening, do I? If so how do i do it?

Comment: There is a reopen tab just next to edit button in my question..

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to have that button